# android studio loads image with twice the size of the image

Tags: java, android

I am working on a game. I have to load a simple image. This is how I do it:

```
(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.context.getResources(), R.drawable.ala))
```

But when i output its width (200) it outputs 400. The same is with the height.

Comment: Please explain your question clearly.

Comment: you mean the width of the original image is 200, but after you decode it from resources,the decoded bitmap width is 400?

Comment: yes    how can I load it with its real size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put the image in drawable-nodpi folder will solve the problem, otherwise when you decode the bitmap from the resources, it will be scale based on density of the screen